# LINUX tcpdump - About IPS and Ports when UDP packet monitoring

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp, packets

I have an online game server running on a vps with linux centos and it keeps dropping players to 0 from time to time, i have discarded problems with the application itself because it does not crash or anything, the players just get disconnected.

I was monitoring packets on my game server port with tcpdump and i caught when that happened and i noticed that an ip adress sent packets without the numerical port like usual (i belive the ip."number" is the ip.port), but is this IP.number the port?

look at the screenshoot:

http://postimg.org/image/6c4k2sdqp/

Differently of all the other normal connections it doesn't send the numerical port, and suddenly the packet listing on the tcpdump stops and my players get dropped from the server.

I was wondering if it was that wich made the connections get dropped for some reason

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the `smart-lm` port is found in the system services list:

```
❯❯❯ grep smart-lm /etc/services
smart-lm        1608/udp    # Smart Corp. License Manager
smart-lm        1608/tcp    # Smart Corp. License Manager
```

And so `tcpdump` is showing that instead of .1608 on the end. It may be a firewall between your network and the remote side (including a firewall or router on the remote side) that's causing the problem.